# Heroku Rails app integrated a Bluehost Wordpress site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, .htaccess, heroku

I have a Rails 4.0 app hosted on Heroku and a Wordpress site hosted on BlueHost.

I'd like to have certain paths forwarded, not redirected, from either the Rails app to Wordpress or the other way around. It doesn't really matter which is the 'master'.

Doing this all hosted on the same box with something like Apache is super easy, but not with my setup.

I've added Rack::Proxy to my Rails middleware stack and can successfully proxy specific paths, e.g. fullpath =~ /^\main/.

I've setup the Wordpress site to be at www.insf.me and my Rails app on Heroku to be www.instructifyme.com.

When I hit www.instructifyme.com/main it forwards over to the Wordpress site, with /main/ stripped off.

Now the problems:

This ends with up, somehow, redirecting to www.insf.me. The proxy does work okay, but Wordpress seems to be doing the redirect.

- The WordPress Address (URL) is set to www.insf.me
- The Site Address (URL) is set to www.insf.me

I've alternately tried setting Site Address to www.instructifyme.com but no love there.

It seems I'm pretty close, but not close enough ;)

Any help, or totally alternate ideas, would be great.

Thanks - Charlie

Answer (score 1):

**Why?**

Wordpress & RoR are both great, but are like oil & water - they don't mix very well

If you're trying to run two applications side-by-side, regardless of *how*, I'd highly recommend looking at *why*

The bottom line is that what you're asking goes against the Rails conventions of [Convention over Configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration). You'll spend more time setting it up than actually making great functionality

---

**CMS**

If you need to have a CMS part to your Rails app, then I would endeavour to build one (especially as a [simple blog app can be done in as little as 15 minutes](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tUH1hewXnC0))

You can probably replicate much of the base-functionality of WP in a couple of days, making it more robust & custom-specced to your own needs. It will also add to your experience as a Rails dev :)

---

**Functionality**

If you're looking to add extra functionality to Wordpress, you might want to consider [writing a plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) for it. WP's main draw is extensibility, so writing a plugin would be a great addition to their community

If you're looking to include a Rails backend to your Wordpress site (maybe you have orders or something), I'd look at using an API to link the two systems. You can [create a Rails API](http://railscasts.com/episodes/348-the-rails-api-gem?view=asciicast) relatively simply, allowing you to send data to your Rails app directly from WP

Comment: The "Why?" is 1) we have a small team, 2) there is no way that we can integrate a CMS into the Rails app that would ever give us the functionality of the Wordpress page builder found in http://elegantthemes.com/preview/Divi 3) our marketing people already know Wordpress 4) I can't see how simple proxy setup has anything to do with Rail's "Convention over configuration".

Comment: Hey Charlie, didn't mean to offend! The convention stuff wasn't about applying a proxy - it was about keeping code, functionality & data dry. I just wanted to give some ideas for you

Comment: Thanks Rich, no worry, no offense taken. We've given the problem and this potential solution a lot of thought. A simple integration of this sort is definitely the easiest and most flexible for our setup. I've read about people having success with Rack::ReverseProxy, but I couldn't get that to work without a redirect. Seems others have had the same issue. In looking at the Rack::ReverseProxy code it's not doing a redirect. That points to Wordpress, which I'm admittedly a rookie at. But I've no idea where the redirect is happening in that case. Thanks!

Comment: Can I ask, though, what are you putting in your ROR system? Are you literally just wanting to use WP as a CMS, with a ROR backend (tickets or something)?

Comment: The ROR system is a SASS the connects independent instructors with students by providing tools to market to those students. Email campaigns, student database, billing, social integration, etc. A big part of this is marketing resources for the instructor. We can provide all the tools in the world, but unless the instructors understand basic online marketing they won't be successful. So, Wordpress fits that bill perfectly.

Comment: I figured it out! I did some more snooping with curl and found that it was the magic trailing '/' that was missing causing a redirect. I added that to the URL I hit Wordpress and it works. No redirect anymore. Now I just need to throw some caching in front of it, or see about using CloudFront and I'll be all set.

Comment: Nice - I surmised as much! So how is the setup? Where does the redirect happen?